# How to serialize correctly? Ajax updates all instances of a django upvote button in a object forloop when pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

OK so I have an index page with items that can be up or downvoted.
The issue is that when I upvote/downvote one item, all items on the page are upvoted/downvoted and the appearance of all buttons on the page all change instead of just the one object that was upvoted/downvoted.

**Can anyone help me serialize each for loop object correctly?**

my index page:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <span id="post_{{forloop.counter}}" data-value="{{post.id}}"></span>
    <button class="vote_action" value="upvote_button"> + </i></button>
    
    <span id="votes_{{forloop.counter}}">{{post.points}}</span>
                                  
    <button class="vote_action" value="downvote_button"> - </button>
{% endfor %}
...
<script type="text/javascript">
 // JQUERY - AJAX SCRIPT FOR voting
 $(document).ready(function(){
   {% for post in posts %}
   $('.vote_action').click(function(e) {
      var postid = document.getElementById('post_{{forloop.counter}}').getAttribute('data-value');
          var button = $(this).attr("value");
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "vote" %}',
            data: {
              postid: postid,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
              action: 'postvote',
              button: button,
            },
            success: function(json){
              if (json.length < 1 || json == undefined) {
                //empty
              }
              document.getElementById("votes_{{forloop.counter}}").innerHTML = json['result']
              //change button looks
              $("#uvb_{{forloop.counter}}").addClass("disabled");
              $("#dvb_{{forloop.counter}}").addClass("disabled");
            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {}
          })
        })
        {% endfor %}
      })
      </script>
```

My views function:

```
@login_required
def post_vote(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'postvote':
        # get information from request about what item id it is
        id = int(request.POST.get('postid'))
        # And also which button was pressed
        button = request.POST.get('button')
        post = Posts.objects.get(id=id)

        if button == 'downvote_button':
            if not post.voters.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                post.voters.add(request.user)
                post.votes +=1
                post.points -=2
                post.save()

        elif button == 'upvote_button':
            if not post.voters.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                post.voters.add(request.user)
                post.votes +=1
                post.points +=2
                post.save()

        # return result
        post.refresh_from_db()
        result = post.points
        return JsonResponse({'result':result})
    pass
```

Comment: why you have your scripts inside for loop ? why not have only one script and use `closest()` and `find()` method of jquery to achieve same ?

Comment: I'm really learning as I go. If you can demonstrate, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the support given by @swati, I was able to get this working correctly as demonstrated below for anyone else having trouble with a similar issue.

**All credit goes to @swati**

HTML portion of the page:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="eachpost"> //<!--add this div-->
    <span id="post_{{forloop.counter}}" data-value="{{post.id}}"></span>
    <button class="vote_action" value="upvote_button" id="uvb_{{forloop.counter}}"> + </i></button>
    //<!--add class here-->
    <span id="votes_{{forloop.counter}}" class="votes_points">{{post.points}}</span>                              
    <button class="vote_action" value="downvote_button" id="dvb_{{forloop.counter}}"> - </button>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The JS/AJAX Section of the page

```
$('.vote_action').click(function(e) {
    //get closest div
      var selector = $(this).closest('div.eachpost');
      var button = $(this).attr("value");
      //find class get id and split to get counter
      var counter =selector.find('.votes_points').attr('id').split('_')
      //get span data-value
      var postid = selector.find("span[id=post_"+counter[1]+"]").attr('data-value');
      
      console.log("postID-->"+postid+"Button-->"+button+"counter[1]-->"+counter[1])
      e.preventDefault();
      //your ajax
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "vote" %}',
        data: {
          postid: postid,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
          action: 'postvote',
          button: button
        },
        success: function(json) {
          if (json.length < 1 || json == undefined) {
            //empty
          }
          //add response to votes_point
          $("#votes_"+counter[1]).text(json['result']);
          //change button looks
          $("#uvb_"+counter[1]).addClass("disabled");
          $("#dvb_"+counter[1]).addClass("disabled");
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {}
      })
     
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `for-loop` for script you can simply use `closest()` and `find()` method of jquery to achieve same .Here are some change you need to make in your **django** code :

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div> //<!--add this div-->
    <span id="post_{{forloop.counter}}" data-value="{{post.id}}"></span>
    <button class="vote_action" value="upvote_button"> + </i></button>
    //<!--add class here-->
    <span id="votes_{{forloop.counter}}" class="votes_points">{{post.points}}</span>                              
    <button class="vote_action" value="downvote_button"> - </button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then , in your jquery code whenever your button is clicked use `closest()` method to get the closest `div` then using this find the `span` where `class="votes_points"` and  get its `id` and use `split` method to get the `{{forloop.counter}}` value.Using this we can easily get `postid` value also . So,your **jquery** code will look like below  :

```
$('.vote_action').click(function(e) {
    //get closest div
      var selector = $(this).closest('div');
      var button = $(this).attr("value");
      //find class get id and split to get counter
      var counter =selector.find('.votes_points').attr('id').split('_')
      //get span data-value
      var postid = selector.find("span[id=post_"+counter[1]+"]").attr('data-value');
      
      console.log("postID-->"+postid+"Button-->"+button+"counter[1]-->"+counter[1])
      e.preventDefault();
      //your ajax
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "vote" %}',
        data: {
          postid: postid,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
          action: 'postvote',
          button: button
        },
        success: function(json) {
          if (json.length < 1 || json == undefined) {
            //empty
          }
          //add response to votes_point
          selector.find('.votes_points').text(json['result'])
          //change button looks
          $("#uvb_"+counter[1]).addClass("disabled");
          $("#dvb_"+counter[1]).addClass("disabled");
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {}
      })
     
    })
```

***Demo Code***(with demo datas) :

```js
$('.vote_action').click(function(e) {
//get closest div
  var selector = $(this).closest('div');
  var button = $(this).attr("value");
  //find class get id and split to get counter
  var counter =selector.find('.votes_points').attr('id').split('_')
  //get span data-value
  var postid = selector.find("span[id=post_"+counter[1]+"]").attr('data-value');
  
  console.log("postID-->"+postid+" || Button-->"+button+" ||   counter[1]-->"+counter[1])
  e.preventDefault();
  //your ajax
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "vote" %}',
    data: {
      postid: postid,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'postvote',
      button: button
    },
    success: function(json) {
      if (json.length < 1 || json == undefined) {
        //empty
      }
      //add response to votes_point
      selector.find('.votes_points').text(json['result'])
      //change button looks
      $("#uvb_"+counter[1]).addClass("disabled");
      $("#dvb_"+counter[1]).addClass("disabled");
    },
    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {}
  })
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="post_1" data-value="1"></span>
  <button class="vote_action" value="upvote_button"> +</button>

  <span id="votes_1" class="votes_points">15</span>
  <button class="vote_action" value="downvote_button"> - </button>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="post_2" data-value="2"></span>
  <button class="vote_action" value="upvote_button"> +</button>

  <span id="votes_2" class="votes_points">52</span>

  <button class="vote_action" value="downvote_button"> - </button>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="post_3" data-value="3"></span>
  <button class="vote_action" value="upvote_button"> +</button>

  <span id="votes_3" class="votes_points">52</span>

  <button class="vote_action" value="downvote_button"> - </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. What do I do in the case where I have other `div`s in between the for loop? I have some things I omitted to keep it simple like bootstrap card divs etc.

```

Comment: You can simply give some `class="something"` to the `outer` div where all your cards and span are there and only thing you need to change in jQuery code is `$(this).closest('div.something')` it should work .

Comment: Thank you. Trying this now!

Comment: Thank you again! You detailed answered was so useful. I made some changes to make it work because when the text was updating from the Json result, it was updating text on all the posts.
I will post the completed answer below for anyone else that may need this. But thank you again